# Show the Java args[] in one line

Tags: java

I wrote this

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i =0; i < args.length; i++){
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

in cmd typed:

```
C:\> javac Main.java

C:\> java Main first second third
```

The console showed me

```
first
second
third
```

Questin is how to make that cmd shows me arguments in one line?

Answer (score 3):

Should be something like this.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i =0; i < args.length; i++){
            System.out.print(args[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using [`System.out.println()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29).

The `println` method will terminate current line by writing the line separator string for you. (Which in your case is the newline character.)

Instead, you want to use [`System.out.print()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29).

Like so:

```
System.out.print(args[i] + " ");
```

This will print your argument, followed by a space instead of a newline character.

Answer (score 1):

Use System.out.print() instead of println().

Comment: Thanks to all. It helped

Answer (score 1):

If you want the printing to continue in the same line, you need to invoke a `print()` method instead of a `println()` method.

Also, since this resembles the `echo` program, if you want it to be perfect, you want to have space between the strings, but not before the first or after the last.

With Java 4 and older:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (i >  0)
                 System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(args[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

With Java 5-7 you could use `for`each-loops, although in this special case that's not really better, it's just for completeness:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        boolean isFirst = true;
        for (final String arg : args) {
            if (isFirst)
                isFirst = false;
            else
                System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(arg);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

With Java 8:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        System.out.println(String.join(" ", args));
    }
}
```

If you want your program to be fast - which would not be necessary in this case, this again is just for completeness - you would want to first assemble the String and then print it in one go.

With Java 4 and older:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0)
                sb.append(' ');
            sb.append(args[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

With Java 5-7:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (final String arg : args)
            sb.append(arg);
        if (args.length > 0)
            sb.setLength(sb.getLength() - 1); // skip last space
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

With Java 8 (no difference):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        System.out.println(String.join(" ", args));
    }
}
```

The code which I prefer:

```
import static java.lang.String.join;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        out.println(join(" ", args));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, have fun with Java!